# Entity with associated entity to DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I want to ask about a good practice to convert Entity with associated entities to DTO's.

So, for example i have 3 enities:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class First {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "first")
    ...
    private List<Second> second;

    @ManyToOne
    ...
    private Third third;


@Entity
@Table
public class Second {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    ...
    private First first;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "second")
    ...
    private List<Third> third;



@Entity
@Table
public class Third {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    ...
    private Second second;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "third")
    ...
    private List<First> first;
```

What is the best practice to convert all of these to DTO's?
I don't want to use external libraries.

Like you see the problem is with recurrency of it and nested assotations.

Greetings.

Edit:
Can somebody give me the names of libraries for mapping DTO used by himself?

Comment: Such a mapping from entity to DTO and vice versa will always boil down to some non-trivial mapping code, usually involving reflection to resolve related fields and storing references in maps in order to resolve cycles.

At the end of the day, this will usually end up becoming a very time-consuming project in itself, and more likely than not you will re-invent the wheel. I'd strongly recommend looking for a suitable mapping library instead.

Comment: So, there is no better way to do that? Can you give me the name of that library? I found some over internet, but maybe you can give me one from your experience.

Comment: I have had good results with [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). It is relatively easy to configure and covers even quite complicated use cases. It easily handles cycles and inheritance.

Comment: Orika is another v. good, xml free library [Orika](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

I recommend to use the custom dto to avoid cycles ( causes StackOverFlowError). Advantage to manage the content you are transferring. Using the entity class above, i constructed the dto below.

I have dependency for lombok like
"org.projectlombok" % "lombok" % lombokVersion

in my build.

Constructed my custom DTO

```
@Data
public class FirstDTO implements Jsonable {
   protected String id; 
   protected ThirdDTO third;

   public FirstDTO(){}

   @JsonCreator
   public FirstDTO(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                     @JsonProperty("third") Third third){
          this.id = id;
          this.third = third;
     }
}
```